# How to reload localStorage VueJS after using this.$router.go(-1);

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This is my Login.vue:

```
mounted() {
    if (localStorage.login) this.$router.go(-1);
},
methods: {
    axios.post(ApiUrl + "/login") {
       ...
    }

    then(response => {
       ...
       localStorage.login = true;
       this.$router.go(0); /* Reload local storage */
    })
}
```

App.vue:

```
mounted() {
      axios
          .get("/user")
          .then(response => {                      
               localStorage.user_id = response.data.user.id;
               localStorage.package_id = response.data.user.package_id;
           })
},
```

Project.vue:

```
mounted() {
     this.user_id = localStorage.user_id
     this.package_id = localStorage.package_id
}
```

With that above code, I cannot get `localStorage.user_id` and `localStorage.package_id` as I expected. But if I change like the follow, it worked.

```
mounted() {
    const self = this
    setTimeout(function () {
      self.user_id = localStorage.user_id
      self.package_id = localStorage.package_id
      self.getProject();
    },1000)
}
```

But I think `setTimeout` not good in that case. Is there any way to refactor this code?
Thank you!

Comment: what is your project structure?

Comment: Is it a SPA application compiled with webpack mix or something like that?

Comment: I'm using Vue CLI

Answer (score 0):

Try this: in your root component (it's usually `const app = new Vue({ ... })`) write the following:

```
import {localStorage} from 'localStorage'; // import your module if necessary
                                            // this is relative to the way you manage your dependencies.

const app = new Vue({

    //...

    data: function() {
        return {
            localStorage: localStorage;
        }
    }
})
```

Now whenever you want to use `localStorage`, access it from root component like this:

```
this.$root.localStorage
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know your project structure ,but I guess it's probably an async issue. You got the user information async, so when `Project.vue` mounted, the request is not complete yet. As a result, the localstorage is empty at the monent.

There are two solutions for this:

1. Make sure `Project.vue` is not rendered before userinfo is complete. For example, things like `<project v-if="userinfo.user_id" />` should works.
2. Use some data binding libary like `vuex` to bind userinfo to `Project.vue` instead of assign it in lifecycle like `mounted` or `created`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes it is an async issue. I've tried vuex. It worked well rendering but `mounted: {console.log(this.user_id)}` it return `0 \\default state`

Comment: Yes, the value inside `mounted` will always be 0 in this case whatever you use vuex or not. As it only call once on mounted, and vuex sync the value later. It's OK in most case.